# Why is flask turning %20 into %2520?

Tags: flask, html-encode

I created a personal CMS project where each page is stored in the database with the following columns: `title`, `url_safe_title`, and `content`.

To create the `url_safe_title`, I used `urllib.parse.quote()` on the original title. So if the page title is "My Page", the `url_safe_title` will be stored as "My%20Page".

On templates, I'd build URLs using `url_for('core.page', page_name = page.url_safe_title)`, where page_name is the expected variable in the view function.

```
@core.route('/<string:page_name>')
def page(page_name):
  # find the relevant entry in db
  return render_template('template.html', page = page)
```

However, the resulting URL becomes "www.example.com/My%2520Page" instead of the expected "www.example.com/My%20Page". I checked the `url_safe_title` value stored in the database, and it's the correct value ("My%20Page").

Interestingly, "My%2520Page" worked when trying to query for a page that has `url_safe_title` as "My%20Page" when I was hosting this app locally. However, it all fell apart when I hosted it online. Unfortunately, the host is a limited cPanel host without any access to the terminal, so I'm unable to find out what the OS is. I only know that the python version is 3.7.8, and my local python version is 3.7.4.

I've also tried using the `|safe` jinja filter when building the URL `url_for('core.page', page_name = page.url_safe_title|safe)`, but that didn't help either. I passed the page.url_safe_title as a variable on its on to show on the page, and "My%20Page" was displayed.

Answer (score 1):

`%2520` means it is getting encoded twice. You should not encode it before storing in the database.  It is just a string.

Comment: Thanks! Do you know why this only happens when hosted online and not when the app is ran locally? Is there any way I can get both to behave the same way?

Comment: It should behave the same way locally and in production